# v-model vue js laravel Сборка

Tags: laravel, vue.js

почему ругается на

```
<form action="" class="search">
   <input type="text"  v-model.lazy="keywords" v-debounce="300" placeholder="Что ищем?">
</form>
```

ошибки

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-59108dcc","hasScoped":false,"buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./resources/assets/js/components/OffersList.vue
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)
  Error compiling template:

  <form action="" class="search">
      <input type="text"  v-model.lazy="keywords" v-debounce="300" placeholder="Что ищем?">
  </form>
  <div class="offers"  v-if="listoffers.length > 0">
      <div class="offer" v-for="offeri in listoffers">
          <img src="img/com-user.png" alt="" class="avatar">
          <div class="data-offer">
              <div class="card">
                  <a href="/offers/" class="text">{{offeri.title}}</a>
                  <p class="fullname">nadinak [Nadinak]</p>
              </div>
              <div class="data-offer-meta">
                  <span class="date">09.03.2019г. 15:15</span>
                  <div class="data-action">
                      <p class="up">
                          <svg class="up"><use xlink:href="#up"></use></svg>
                          <span>1</span>
                      </p>
                      <p class="down">
                          <svg class="up"><use xlink:href="#up"></use></svg>
                          <span>1</span>
                      </p>
                      <p class="comments">
                          <svg class="comment"><use xlink:href="#comment"></use></svg>
                          <span>0</span>
                      </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

      </div>
  </div>

  - Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead.

 @ ./resources/assets/js/components/OffersList.vue 6:23-266
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/e/extremje/trioscenter/.npm/_logs/2019-06-09T14_47_56_239Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/e/extremje/trioscenter/.npm/_logs/2019-06-09T14_47_56_252Z-debug.log
(docker) extremje_trios@cartman:~/trios [2] $
```

сам компонент

```
<template>
    <form action="" class="search">
        <input type="text"  v-model="keywords" placeholder="Что ищем?" value="" >
    </form>
    <div class="loading" v-if="loading">
        Loading...
    </div>
    <div class="offers"  v-if="listoffers.length > 0">
        <div class="offer" v-for="offeri in listoffers">
            <img src="img/com-user.png" alt="" class="avatar">
            <div class="data-offer">
                <div class="card">
                    <a href="/offers/" class="text">{{offeri.title}}</a>
                    <p class="fullname">nadinak [Nadinak]</p>
                </div>
                <div class="data-offer-meta">
                    <span class="date">09.03.2019г. 15:15</span>
                    <div class="data-action">
                        <p class="up">
                            <svg class="up"><use xlink:href="#up"></use></svg>
                            <span>1</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="down">
                            <svg class="up"><use xlink:href="#up"></use></svg>
                            <span>1</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="comments">
                            <svg class="comment"><use xlink:href="#comment"></use></svg>
                            <span>0</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Component template should contain exactly one root element

Перевод: должен быть один корневой элемент

Структура кода должна быть следующей:

```
<template>
 <div>
   <form action="" class="search">
    <input type="text"  v-model="keywords" placeholder="Что ищем?" value="" >
</form>
<div class="loading" v-if="loading">
    Loading...
</div>
<div class="offers"  v-if="listoffers.length > 0">
    <div class="offer" v-for="offeri in listoffers">
        <img src="img/com-user.png" alt="" class="avatar">
        <div class="data-offer">
            <div class="card">
                <a href="/offers/" class="text">{{offeri.title}}</a>
                <p class="fullname">nadinak [Nadinak]</p>
            </div>
            <div class="data-offer-meta">
                <span class="date">09.03.2019г. 15:15</span>
                <div class="data-action">
                    <p class="up">
                        <svg class="up"><use xlink:href="#up"></use></svg>
                        <span>1</span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="down">
                        <svg class="up"><use xlink:href="#up"></use></svg>
                        <span>1</span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="comments">
                        <svg class="comment"><use xlink:href="#comment"></use></svg>
                        <span>0</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

Comment: добавил в вопрос структуру

Comment: поправил ответ с учетом вашей структуры.
Вам надо form, div с классами loading и offers обернуть в один общий div

Comment: а подскажите, что за ошибка в консоле выскакивает ncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined